# Form sends values using GET instead of POST

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

myWhen the submit button is hit the page reloads showing the input values in the URL as if it was using GET. Nothing else happens. Not even the validation functions are run.

```
<?php echo form_open("auth/login"); ?>

    <label for="inputClientID" class="sr-only">Client ID</label>
    <input type="clientID" name="clientID" id="inputClientID" class="form-control" placeholder="Client ID" required autofocus>
    <label for="inputloginID" class="sr-only">Login ID</label>
    <input type="loginID" name="loginID" id="inputloginID" class="form-control" placeholder="Login ID" required>
    <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
    <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Login</button>

<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

I am using PHP CodeIgniter. I have tried to build the form using plain HTML instead of CI form_open() method - still shows the same issue.

This is how the code is loaded in the browser, apparently it's fine:

```
<form action="https://mywebsite.com/auth/login" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">

    <label for="inputClientID" class="sr-only">Client ID</label>
    <input type="clientID" name="clientID" id="inputClientID" class="form-control" placeholder="Client ID" required autofocus>
    <label for="inputloginID" class="sr-only">Login ID</label>
    <input type="loginID" name="loginID" id="inputloginID" class="form-control" placeholder="Login ID" required>
    <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
    <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Login</button>

</form>
```

Then, this is how the url looks like after the submit button is hit and the page reloads:

```
https://mywebsite.com/?clientID=1&loginID=samplelogin
```

It started to happened after my partner added some formatting using BootStrap (maybe it's only coincidence).

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

<< "Auth/Login" >>

```
 public function login() {
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('clientID', 'Client ID', 'required|numeric');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('loginID', 'Login ID', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        $this->load->view('defaultheader', array('title' =>
            "MyWebsite | Login"));
        $this->load->view("loginpage");
    } else {
        echo "it works";
        $clientID = $this->input->post("clientID");
        $loginID = $this->input->post("loginID");
        $password = $this->input->post("password");

        $user_check = $this->auth_model->check_credentials($clientID, $loginID, $password);

        switch ($user_check) {
            case 1:
                $this->check_first_access($loginID,$clientID);
                break;
            case 0:
                $message = "Wrong Client ID / Login ID / Password combination.";
                $this->load->view('defaultheader');
                $this->load->view('loginpage', array('message' => $message));
                break;
            case -1:
                $message = "User deactivated";
                $this->load->view('defaultheader');
                $this->load->view('loginpage', array('message' => $message));
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

- It doesn't show any validation error

<< routes file >>

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'home';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

<< .htaccess file >>

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|mywebsite|phpmyadmin|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: disable javascript on browser and see if this happens again

Comment: You can use [post_get()](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/input.html#CI_Input::post_get) method to collect all data from request.

Comment: Form method is post and u r using get?

Comment: Just simple use $_REQUEST if u r not sure the method

Comment: Is it fine? auth/login

Comment: @Tpojka I am not sure if that is right move. Right now, I am getting the values using $this->input->post(). I've never had any problem with that. I feel like my Auth controller is even being called because the URL doesn't change showing it

Comment: @devpro Form method is POST. But apparently when the form is submitted it sends the values via GET, and at the same time the controller is not loaded.

Comment: @devpro yes, that function and the controller are both fine

Comment: @ArefAnafgeh I have commented the js files in the header and the same code was tested in different browsers and O.S. Do you think it would still make any difference to disable javascript?

Comment: i guessed that a js had been written that submit the form in get method

Comment: To help more we need to know more. For example, `auth/login` code, `routes` code and `.htaccess` code at least. This way question is too broad and too less info is given to know what is going on. If you want values from URL, than use method I suggested. Same is @devpro's except mine is CI way. If someone added something to your code, we don't have a chance to know what it is. No chance without crystal ball at least. Or your edit of question. :)

Comment: @Tpojka thanks for the heads up. Just added the codes you suggested.

Comment: Maybe itis in browser cache. Shift+F5 to clear it (on Windows), restart Apache too. Maybe it was built, changed but left in cache of the browser.

Comment: This is good detail first of all hit yut url directly.... sitename/auth/login ..... and chk what errors r u gettig or redirect on other page.

Comment: Second atleast fix yur input fields.. add name attribute in password field otherwise u cant get either use post or get

Comment: What's going on in `$this->check_first_access()`? Only place where it's not clear what is going on with the input params - which are also what's showing up in the url.  Used firebug or Developer Tools to see what kind of headers are going back and forth?

Comment: @devpro I did all suggestions. Nothing has changed, actually now that I set a name to the password field it also shows the password in the url after the page reloads lol. When I hit auth/login it simply load the login page s saying "wrong password or username" which is the expected message since input->post() has nothing

Comment: Have you restart Apache?

Comment: @DFriend it checks if that is the first time the user is accessing the website by querying a log table in the db. It asks the user to change the password if so.

   public function check_first_access($loginID,$clientID) {
        
        if ($this->auth_model->check_first_login($loginID)) {
            $this->redefine_password($loginID,$clientID);
        } else {
            $this->open_session($clientID, $loginID);
        }
    }

Comment: @Tpojka that's the only thing I haven't tried yet. I don't have access to the server. I will ask my partner who got the rights to try that.

Comment: Listen to @DFriend of catching Developer Tools data.

Comment: If we assume the actual issue is that CI form behave like get method instead of post

Comment: I assume this will work <?php echo form_open("auth/login", array ("method"=>"post")); ?>

Comment: @devpro I've done that already as it was sugested by other folk here. It didn't work either. Man, I've given up for now. My partner will revert all changes he did before the issue started (even though he only added some css and changed some views)

Comment: Just for testing move php code in index function and remove action from form param

Comment: Check your scripts. You most certainly have a js function executing when you submit the form.

Comment: @Kisaragi Thanks for the suggestion. I have tried to disable every js script and nothing has changed.  I am still waiting for my partner to restore the changes he's done

Comment: change the class of your button and resubmit.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code for form with get method

```
$data = array(
              'method' => 'get'
              );
echo form_open('auth/login', $data);
```

Comment: But I want to use POST. So I did
    $data = array(
              'method' => 'post'
              );
echo form_open('auth/login', $data);

It didn't work

Comment: Sorry, with post method you can not send form values with form action url.

Comment: Yes, I know it. That's exactly the issue. It is automatically doing action url and my code has nothing that allows such behavior

Answer (score 0):

You need to add ending slash:

```
<?php echo form_open("auth/login/"); ?>
```

Comment: I put it. Nothing changed.

Comment: Than its difficult to guess are u using routes for this method and class? Else u did nt have idea than chk $_REQUEST are u getting values?  @leandro

Comment: And also hit yur url directly on browser than u r usig in form action u will get the idea @leandro

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if this is it - but i would try changing the form fields to type='text'

so like this

```
<input type="clientID" name="clientID" id="inputClientID" class="form-control" placeholder="Client ID" required autofocus>
```

change to

```
<input type="text" name="clientID" id="inputClientID" class="form-control" placeholder="Client ID" required autofocus>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I have tried that before though. It didn't work. I am still waiting for my partner to restore the changes he's done